# .htaccess redirect certain virtual directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, conditional-statements

*/podcast/wp/* is a folder, everything else is a virtual directory already generated by RewriteEngine. Here's the code provided by WordPress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /podcast/wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /podcast/wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to redirect **all** requests in the *wp/* directory (except for existing folders)

**excluding** the following possible paths (also virtual directories):

```
/podcast/wp/ANYSTRING1/ANYSTRING2/feed
```

to another domain:

```
example.com
```

using .htaccess while the excluded path remains working as is.
The goal is to "hide" (redirect) the entire WordPress blog except for the feeds.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the wordpress generated rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /podcast/wp/

# new stuff
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^/]+/[^/]+/feed$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,R]

# original wordpress stuff
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /podcast/wp/index.php [L]
```

Depending on how you want to handle the redirect, you can tweak the rule that redirects to `http://example.com/`. If you want 301 permanent redirects, add a `301`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

If you want to preserve the relative URI in the redirect, use a backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

If you want to preserve the entire URI (including the `/podcast/wp/` part, use the URI:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```